# Regular expression for quotes in php and js

Tags: php, regex

I need to change bad quotes `“”` and `""` to `„“`.
For example I will take a few sentences with a bad input and what it should look like after a replace:

Bad input: `„Do It“: „Another sentence in quotes“ “Bayern”`

Good output: `„Do It“: „Another sentence in quotes“ „Bayern“`

Another example: 
Bad input: `„Do It“: „Another "sentence" in “Bayer” quotes“ “Ba “yer” n”` 
Good output: `„Do It“: „Another „sentence“ in „Bayer“ quotes“ „Ba „yer“ n“`

The tricky thing is that the same quote `“` is used in a good quotes (at the end) and in a bad quotes (at the beginning).

Comment: Do you need to change only the quotes or what is in between them?

Comment: I need to change only the quotes. But as told, if quotes are in quotes I need to change all of them.

Comment: You could just use a couple of simple `str_replace()`?

Comment: I can't since in text there is a lot of quotes and I'm need to know which to change, count and so on. Regex is the only way to do this properly.

Comment: @chris85, thank you, it's good

Comment: Okay and now what should the outcome of that be? I think http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php might be your answer... or you need to change the left double quote to a double low quote, regardless of symbol or entity?

Comment: @chris85, &ldquo;Ba&ldquo;Bayern&rdquo;yern&rdquo; should be &bdquo;Ba&bdquo;Bayern&ldquo;yern&ldquo;. This is example with bad quotes inside bad quotes. Another example where bad quotes are in good quotes: &bdquo;Do &ldquo;Bayern&rdquo; It&ldquo; It should return &bdquo;Do &bdquo;Bayern&ldquo; It&ldquo; Also it can be entities and symbols in two ways.

Comment: @mickmackusa counting quotes part I have. The hardest way is to write regex pattern which can detect for example: `“Ba“Bayern”yern”` quotes in quotes with groups. Also I need to do this in js.

Comment: How complex might the nesting be?  Please edit your question to include a comprehensive set of possible strings and the expected output.  I'll solve this for you if you can clarify.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I edited the question. Maybe now it will be more clear what I need to do. Thank you for a help.

Comment: I think I understand now.  I will post a simple pattern for you in a few hours when I get to my computer.

Comment: @mickmackusa why do you think my expected result are not correct? They are all correct. Why? Good quotes in Lithuania are `„“`. Image that i copied text from english source which is using `""` or `“”` quotes. I translated text, but forgot about the quotes. So these my bad inputs not everytime but can be when you mixing few different sources of text for example. So I need a tool which can be universal to translate these quotes as I expected. Your regex now destroy also good quotes which we are using all the time.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I found a solution with using regex. `/(„)((?!.*„).*?)(”)/g` This pattern let select nested quotes. First of all, I count bad quotes. Then I use for loop to match all nested quotes. Since `„` quote exist in good quotes and bad quotes, every time when I picking quotes with this pattern, I changing `„` quote to fake. When for loop is finished , I use another regex pattern to match fake quote and replace it. And actually it works in all ways. Only one problem is that I can't pick nested `""` quotes, since all symbols are equal and is very hard to find which quotes are nested.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oLZv00/1)):

```
([“])+|([”])+
```

**Edit:** Try something like this in your php to replace them individually :

```
$str = '“Ba“Bayern”yern”';
$replaced = preg_replace(['/“/', '/”/'], ['„', '“'], $str);
```

Comment: But I need replace “ quotes to „ and ” quote to “. Can you somehow modify this regex?

Comment: I need regex, since if I will have bad quotes inside good quotes for example, it will destroy also good quotes. For example: „Do  Bayern”  It“ since good quotes „Do It“ and bad quotes Bayern” has the same one quote.

Comment: @mega6382 Why involve `preg_replace_callback` here? `preg_replace` can take arrays, but even simpler would be `str_replace`, `str_replace(array('“', '”'), array('„', '“'), $string)`. You also don't need a character class for a single character.

Comment: @chris85 Image this sentence -> „Do It“: „Another sentence“ “Bayern”. Do it and Another sentence using good quotes, and Bayern not. If I use str_replace, it destroys good quotes.

Comment: @anhelo Please show the `str_replace` usage that destroys good quotes. It should only modify the found character(s).

Comment: @chris85, &ldquo; entity or quote “ are in both good and bad quotes combinatiot: in good quotes it's ends, in bad quotes it' starts. So i can't replace this symbol for good quotes usage, only for bad, so why I should check it with regex only when starting quote are &ldquo; and finishing quote are &rdquo;. Sometime it can be than bad quotes are in bad quotes so I need then select all these quotes. Now my regex selects only outside quotes.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks, completely forgot about that.

Comment: @mega6382 preg_replace works on this sentence but I have sentence where bad quotes are near or inside quotes, replace works bad: „Do It“: „Another good quotes“ “Bayern” return „Do It„: „Another good quotes„ „Bayern“ output, which destroys good quotes but change well bad quotes :( I'm messing with this for two days...

Comment: @anhelo Provide me a string with both good and bad quotes, enclose it in \`\` and post it here.

Comment: @mega6382 Good quotes: `„Do It“`, bad quotes `“Bayern”`, but don't forget, that both combination of quotes has the same quote `“` but are in different position. In text can be different ways of quotes combinatios, for example `“Ba“Bayern”yern”` where bad quotes are inside bad quotes, `„Do “Bayern” It“` where bad quotes are inside good quotes, `„Do It“ “Bayern”` where bad quotes are near good quotes. In differebt situation, quote replace should replace only bad quotes, not good quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To say that I have toiled away at this is an understatement.  I put my tinfoil hat on and tested my patterns against as many uncooperative strings and fringe cases as I could.  If you discover a valid quoted expression that is not matched by my pattern(s), please leave me a comment and I'll see if I can patch up my solution.

That said, I have made some assumptions:

- All quotations are balanced (every opening quotation mark is paired/closed by the correct, related quotation mark).  e.g. `“` is followed by `”`, `"` is followed by `"`, and `„` is followed by `“`
- Nested quotations are never more than 2 layers.  This means there are no "grandparent" quotations; only "lone" and "parent - child" quotations will occur.
- I have built the patterns to accommodate "squished quotes" -- meaning two separate quoted expressions can be written side-by-side without a space separating them.
- Leading quotation marks MAY NOT have a space immediately following them (This would only occur in sloppy/invalid input).
- Trailing quotation marks MAY NOT have a space immediately preceding them (This would only occur in sloppy/invalid input), but may have `0 or more` punctuation marks.  This consideration allows `"Then she said..."` and `“The price is WHAT?!?”`

The short explanation:

### My one-function method corrects quotations in two waves (two patterns each wave).

- Pattern #1 replaces "bad curly double quotes" around "lone" and "nested" quotes.
- Pattern #2 replaces "bad standard double quotes" around "lone" and "nested" quotes.
- Pattern #3 replaces "bad curly double quotes" around "parent" quotes ONLY.
- Pattern #4 replaces "bad standard double quotes" around "parent" quotes ONLY.

[Wave 1 Pattern Demo (I piped #1 and #2 together)](https://regex101.com/r/T7uGby/2)

[Wave 2 Pattern Demo (I piped #3 and #4 together)](https://regex101.com/r/8YZXmU/1)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9d922da5929b11b5a9382cd583ab9534ca1d7814))

```
$ins_outs=[
    '“Lone Bad Quote” 
    "Lone Bad Quote."
    „Lone Good Quote“
    „Start Good Parent "Bad Child?" „Good Child,“ “Bad Child...” End Good Parent!“
    "Start Bad Parent „Good Child!“ “Bad Child???” "Bad Child," End Bad Parent?"
    “Start Bad Parent „Good Child.“ End Bad Parent”
    „Start Good Parent “Bad Child,” End Good Parent“
    "Start Bad Parent “Bad Child,” End Bad Parent"'
    =>
    '„Lone Bad Quote“ 
    „Lone Bad Quote.“
    „Lone Good Quote“
    „Start Good Parent „Bad Child?“ „Good Child,“ „Bad Child...“ End Good Parent!“
    „Start Bad Parent „Good Child!“ „Bad Child???“ „Bad Child,“ End Bad Parent?“
    „Start Bad Parent „Good Child.“ End Bad Parent“
    „Start Good Parent „Bad Child,“ End Good Parent“
    „Start Bad Parent „Bad Child,“ End Bad Parent“',
    '„Do It“: „Another sentence in quotes“ “Bayern”'=>'„Do It“: „Another sentence in quotes“ „Bayern“',
    '„Do It“: „Another "sentence" in “Bayer” quotes“ “Ba “yer” n”'=>'„Do It“: „Another „sentence“ in „Bayer“ quotes“ „Ba „yer“ n“',
    '“Ba“Bayern”yern”'=>'„Ba„Bayern“yern“',
    '„Do “Bayern” It“'=>'„Do „Bayern“ It“',
    '„Do It“: „Another good quotes“ “Bayern”'=>'„Do It“: „Another good quotes“ „Bayern“'
];
foreach($ins_outs as $input=>$expected){
    echo " input = $input\n";
    //   $bad_inners=preg_replace(['/“(\b[^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*)”/u','/"\b([^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*)"/u'],'„$1“',$input);
    //                                                             $bad_outers=preg_replace(['/“\b((?:[^"“”„]*„\b[^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*“[^"“”„]*)+\b[,.!?]*)”/u','/"\b((?:[^"“”„]*„\b[^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*“[^"“”„]*)+\b[,.!?]*)"/u'],'„$1“',$replace_bad_inners);
    echo "output = ",preg_replace(['/“(\b[^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*)”/u','/"\b([^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*)"/u','/“\b((?:[^"“”„]*„\b[^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*“[^"“”„]*)+\b[,.!?]*)”/u','/"\b((?:[^"“”„]*„\b[^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*“[^"“”„]*)+\b[,.!?]*)"/u'],'„$1“',$input),"\n";
    //                               ^^^------inners1 ------^^^  ^^^------inners2 ------^^^   ^^^-----------------------outers1 -----------------------^^^   ^^^-----------------------outers2 -----------------------^^^
    echo "expect = $expected\n---\n";
}
```

I'll admit the regex patterns look rather convoluted at first glance.  The good news is, once you separate the four patterns and break them into logical chunks, reading them is simplified.

`/“(\b[^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*)”/u` - match all non-parent curly quotations (no internal quotes) and allow punctuation.

`/"\b([^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*)"/u` - match all non-parent standard quotations (no internal quotes) and allow punctuation.

`/“\b((?:[^"“”„]*„\b[^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*“[^"“”„]*)+\b[,.!?]*)”/u` - match all parent curly quotations.  Parent quotes must contain one or more valid child quotations with optional leading and trailing text (the text may not contain any type of loose/unmatched double quote characters)

`/"\b((?:[^"“”„]*„\b[^"“”„]+\b[,.!?]*“[^"“”„]*)+\b[,.!?]*)"/u` - match all parent standard quotations.  Parent quotes must contain one or more valid child quotations with optional leading and trailing text (the text may not contain any type of loose/unmatched double quote characters)

These four patterns are replaced by the same string each time `„$1“`.
My patterns should work seamlessly in both php and javascript.
...I didnt' bother to code up the javascript equivalent, I'll leave you something to play with ;)

Comment: @anhelo How did I do?